# RC and RL circuit transient behaviour

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor

### 1st case

I have a R-L series circuit and i connect a DC current source in series with it connected by a switch  and then  close the switch

### 2nd case

I have a R-C series circuit and i connect a DC source in series with it connected by a switch and close the switch.

Assuming initial conditions to be zero in both cases, I wanted to understand  intuitively how will these two circuits behave just after closing the switch and which case is dangerous practically for a finite value of source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *which case is dangerous practically for a finite value of source*

Nothing is dangerous until you provide real details of the components and the current source that powers the circuits. However, it is likely that the RL series circuit will produce the biggest problem because you are trying to change the inductor current from zero to some non-zero value in an instant and that requires infinite voltage to do so: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}$$

That equation is for an inductor and if \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ is infinite (i.e. a sudden change required in current) then the voltage will also be infinite.

It's not initially a problem for the series RC circuit except that the voltage will grow and grow across the capacitor because the current is constant and you are continuously charging it. The voltage will rise to infinity in infinite time theoretically.